# Mediaplayer for Android

Tags: android, media-player, vlc

My dad is using a lifetab E10320 using android 4.2.2. Not sure whether they were installed by Medion or himself, but he had *LIFE Player* and *Videoplayer" installed. Both videoplayers were running quick smooth, but he was complaining about the low sound volume, so I downloaded VLC player for him and the sound was nice, but now the video stutters. That's why I wondered what you guys would recommend for a smooth android mediaplayer with a possible sound boost. Subtitles are used almost exclusively, so the interface should make subtitles easy to use.

The movie I was trying to play was a 7.49 GB 1080p mkv file, while the tablet only supports up to 720p if I check youtube for max resolution. The first two mentioned players worked smooth and scrolling to the movie went without any delay, while VLC player make the image stutter.

Answer (score 1):

After installing and using many options, I finally settled onto [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en). It has plenty of configurable controls (yet fairly easy to use) and features a nice hardware-codec mode that can greatly improve your video performance, provided your hardware supports it.

Comment: my first impression is not really user-friendly as the videos on the SD card aren't included in the maps view...